# Is prostate massage permisible in Islam if the wife does it?

Tags: sex

I have discovered recently that a middle age scientist called *Freud* said that absolute orgasm of the man is not reachable until anal penetration. So I came to know about prostate massage and how it is done by doctors to cure some prostatic diseases and others.

In Islam homosexuality is haram *but* is it permissible for a man's wife to put 2cm of her finger in his anus to reach the prostate, for the purpose of massage?